# Cast value from NSNotification's object

Tags: objective-c

How can I cast the object in a NSNotification to an integer and to a string?  When I log the notification to the console I get...

NSConcreteNotification 0x20af70 {name = kMessageCountNotification; object = 1}

But when I set the text value of a UILabel to that value, I get 72855952

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do or what do you need to happen?  Can you show some code?

Comment: [self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", note.object]];

note is an NSNotification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation of class that has sent this notification should contain information what type of notification is this and what does it send in its object.

You can access object sent using `object` method:

```
ClassOfObjectSent *obj = [notification_you_have_received object];
```

Note that it is a pointer to an object, not a scalar value. If object is `NSNumber`, you can get `int` this way:

```
int i = [obj intValue];
```

If it's a `NSString` you could use it directly or – safer – create your own copy (if you use Cocoa Touch or build non-GC Mac app, you'll have to `release` the copy).

```
NSString *txt = [obj copy];
```

Comment: You'll also have to `release` the copy if you're targeting a system without garbage collection, or building an application extension that supports but doesn't require garbage collection.